# problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. > problem occurred configuring project ':app'.Cannot invoke method afterEvaluate() on null object

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-gridview

Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\developement\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 421
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot invoke method afterEvaluate() on null object

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

> 

[image]
how to solve this problem a search a lot but any solution have